# Appcelerator setup on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to setup appcelerator on windows. I have installed and below are the details:

C:\Users\emmanuelfrancis>appc ti info -t windows
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.1
Copyright (c) 2014-2018, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  No versions found

Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
  10.0 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\

Windows PowerShell
    Enabled                   = yes

Windows Phone Emulators
10.0

Windows Phone Devices

Windows Issues
  ×  Microsoft Visual Studio not found.
     You will be unable to build Windows Phone or Windows Store apps.
     You can install it from http://appcelerator.com/visualstudio.

Installed MS and it exists in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio

Can anyone help how to resolve "No versions found" for Microsoft Visual Studio"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C++ Universal Windows Platform Tools" was missing. Installed it and all set now.